# rewrite problem : put magento inside drupal installation directory

Tags: drupal, .htaccess, magento

I have put magento inside a drupal installation in a subdirectory called store.

When I access http://localhost/myshop/store magento home page is showed without problem but when i try to access any link inside magento (example http://localhost/myshop/store/admin) i get a drupal page that tells me that the page is not found !

What should I do to make all request under /store path be dispatched to magento insted of drupal ?

Comment: What does your .htaccess file look like?

Comment: I have the same problem and both solutions doesn't help me. I'm getting 404 on any magento page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit your .htaccess rewrite path to be /myshop

```
############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

#RewriteBase /magento/
```

look for this in .htaccess and uncomment RewriteBase and change /magento/ to your directory name

Comment: yes I want to know how to do it exactly. I don't know .hetaccess just the basics

Comment: edited my answer,. look for this in htaccess and uncomment rewritebase and change magento to your dir name

Answer (score 1):

In the `.htaccess` file for Drupal - that is, `/myshop/.htaccess` - add the following *before* the line with `RewriteRule` in it.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/store/
```

This excludes your Magento directory from Drupal's rewriting and so allow Magento to continue as normal. You shouldn't need to change Magento's `/myshop/store/.htaccess` file for this.